# How to get the session values in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, ccavenue

here is my samle request.jsp

```
pageContext.setAttribute("test", "ccavenue", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);

<form id="nonseamless" method="post" name="redirect" action="http://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"/> 
    <input type="hidden" id="encRequest" name="encRequest" value="<%= encRequest %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="access_code" id="access_code" value="<%= accessCode %>">
    <script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>
</form>
```

here is my response.jsp like

```
String test = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("test", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
out.print(test);
```

i am setting the pageContext value in request.jsp, redirect the request to ccavenue site and they send the response to response.jsp but in response.jsp getting the pageContext value is null

please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `session` instead:

```
session.setAttribute("test", "ccavenue");
```

*response.jsp*

```
String test = (String) session.getAttribute("test");
```

***pageContext.setAttribute()*:**

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#SESSION_SCOPE)

> Session scope (only valid if this page participates in a session): the
>   named reference remains available from the HttpSession (if any)
>   associated with the Servlet until the HttpSession is invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pageContext use **request.setAttribute("val","value")** in *request.jsp* and **request.getAttribute("val")** in *response.jsp* or set to session and use **value="${value}"** in jsp

Answer (score 0):

## PageScope

> What you put on your `page scope` is available only for the JSP page
>   that put it. Any other page in the same request included via or
>   forwarded will not see object in the first page scope.

May be you should try `Session scope` or `Request Scope` for that !!

Comment: i have tryied using session and request i am getting null values